# Top align bullet in a radio button

Tags: silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-7, radio-button

Newbie to XAML and WP7 phone developement here.

I have a radio button that has a textblock in it.  The text in the textblock spans across multiple lines.  When this happens, the bullet is centered on the text, but I would like it to be aligned to the top.  I'm assuming I need to override the property but I can't seem to figure it out.

Here's the XAML for my radio button.  Any ideas on how I can get the bullet to align to the top of the text and not centered?

```
<RadioButton x:Name="RadioButton1" Background="#BFD0A225" Margin="0,-12,0,-13" Checked="itsChecked" FontSize="32">
     <TextBlock x:Name="TextBlockText" TextWrapping="Wrap">
         <Run Text="This is line 1."/>
         <LineBreak/>
         <Run Text="This is line 2."/>
         <LineBreak />
         <Run Text="This is line 3."/>
     </TextBlock>
</RadioButton>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try and apply this style to your radio button?

```
<RadioButton x:Name="RadioButton1" Background="#BFD0A225" FontSize="32" Style="{StaticResource RadioButtonStyle1}">





    <Style x:Key="PhoneButtonBase" TargetType="ButtonBase">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{StaticResource PhoneBorderThickness}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilySemiBold}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeMediumLarge}"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10,3,10,5"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ButtonBase">
                    <Grid Background="Transparent">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneBackgroundBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Transparent"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Border x:Name="ButtonBackground" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CornerRadius="0" Margin="{StaticResource PhoneTouchTargetOverhang}">
                            <ContentControl x:Name="ContentContainer" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="PhoneRadioButtonCheckBoxBase" BasedOn="{StaticResource PhoneButtonBase}" TargetType="ToggleButton">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource PhoneRadioCheckBoxBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource PhoneRadioCheckBoxBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeMedium}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="RadioButtonStyle1" BasedOn="{StaticResource PhoneRadioButtonCheckBoxBase}" TargetType="RadioButton">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="RadioButton">
                    <Grid Background="Transparent">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="EnabledCheckBackground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="PressedDarkCheckBackground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="PressedLightCheckBackground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="CheckMark">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneRadioCheckBoxCheckBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="EnabledCheckBackground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="DisabledDarkCheckBackground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="DisabledLightCheckBackground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="CheckMark">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneRadioCheckBoxCheckDisabledBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="CheckMark">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unchecked"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Indeterminate"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ValidationStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Valid"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="InvalidFocused"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="InvalidUnfocused"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Focused"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Grid Margin="{StaticResource PhoneTouchTargetLargeOverhang}">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="32"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid x:Name="Radio" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,10,0,0">
                                <Ellipse x:Name="EnabledCheckBackground" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="32" IsHitTestVisible="False" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="32"/>
                                <Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="32" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="{StaticResource PhoneDarkThemeOpacity}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="32">
                                    <Ellipse x:Name="PressedDarkCheckBackground" Fill="{StaticResource PhoneRadioCheckBoxPressedBrush}" Height="32" Visibility="Collapsed" Width="32"/>
                                    <Ellipse x:Name="DisabledDarkCheckBackground" Fill="{StaticResource PhoneRadioCheckBoxDisabledBrush}" Height="32" Visibility="Collapsed" Width="32"/>
                                </Canvas>
                                <Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="32" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="{StaticResource PhoneLightThemeOpacity}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="32">
                                    <Ellipse x:Name="PressedLightCheckBackground" Fill="{StaticResource PhoneRadioCheckBoxPressedBrush}" Height="32" Stroke="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}" StrokeThickness="{StaticResource PhoneStrokeThickness}" Visibility="Collapsed" Width="32"/>
                                    <Ellipse x:Name="DisabledLightCheckBackground" Fill="{StaticResource PhoneRadioCheckBoxDisabledBrush}" Height="32" Stroke="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}" StrokeThickness="{StaticResource PhoneStrokeThickness}" Visibility="Collapsed" Width="32"/>
                                </Canvas>
                                <Ellipse x:Name="CheckMark" Fill="{StaticResource PhoneRadioCheckBoxCheckBrush}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="16" IsHitTestVisible="False" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="16" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                            </Grid>
                            <ContentControl x:Name="ContentContainer" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Grid.Column="1" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="12,0,0,0" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Comment: This is very close.  Thanks!  The only issue that I see is the dot in a checked radio button is a little too low.  Which part of the above XAML can I use to tweak it a little bit up?

Comment: Sorry i wasn't careful. I just edited the style and now it should be working fine. The place you should be looking at is a Grid called 'Radio'. Hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to modify the default control to do this. Simply customize the margin for the `TextBlock` control that you are using inside the `RadioButton`:

```
<RadioButton  x:Name="RadioButton1" Background="#BFD0A225" Margin="0,-12,0,-13" Checked="itsChecked" FontSize="32">
    <TextBlock Margin="0,90,0,0" x:Name="TextBlockText" TextWrapping="Wrap">
         <Run Text="This is line 1."/>
         <LineBreak/>
         <Run Text="This is line 2."/>
         <LineBreak />
         <Run Text="This is line 3."/>
    </TextBlock>
</RadioButton>
```

Comment: ahhh that makes sense.  Thanks!  I think I'll stick with the other one for now since I've already implemented it.